# Google JWT Invalid Signature from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, digital-signature, jwt, google-oauth

I am trying to authenticate via a service account from Salesforce.com to Google's DFP.  I had the integration working under a previous user/credential pair, but am required to update to a new user.

I created the project/user/key pair in the Google Developer Console and added the new service account to the network in DFP.  I then changed the "iss" value to be the new user's email and the private key to be the new private key from the keypair.

I am now receiving an 'Invalid Signature' error.

In SFDC, I am using Crypto.sign method with RSA-SHA256.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_sign

I have validated the key format to be PKCS#8 with header and new line characters removed per the documentation (I went so far as to decode the ASN.1 format and inspect the nodes for conformity).

Have I missed a step in the connection between the user and the correct credential?  Is there a way for me to validate the signature that I am producing locally to see where I am going wrong?  The only difference I have seen is that the old private key was shorter than the current private key.

Below is the code I am using to generate the JWT (again, this code functioned properly with a different username and credential key).

```
JWTHeader head = new JWTHeader();
head.alg = 'RS256';
head.typ = 'JWT';

JWTClaimSet claim = new JWTClaimSet();
claim.iss = '<username>@*.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
claim.scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfp';
claim.aud = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
claim.iat = DateTime.now().getTime() / 1000;
claim.exp = claim.iat + 3600;

System.debug(JSON.serialize(head));
System.debug(JSON.serialize(claim));

String key = '<privatekey>’;
String base = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(head))), 'UTF-8') + '.' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(claim))), 'UTF-8');
String sig = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.sign('RSA-SHA256', Blob.valueOf(base), EncodingUtil.base64Decode(key))), 'UTF-8');
String body = base + '.' + sig;
System.debug(body);

Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
req.setBody('grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=' + body);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Days later I found another solution that solved the issue.  The problem was the base64urlsafe encoding.  This encoding is not natively done in SFDC and perscribes the removal of trailing padding characters from the base64 string.  Luckily, my original username encoded with no padding characters in the claim set.  With the new username, the padding characters are present and must be removed before signing.

It all comes down to just a few characters.